# UV mapping on Cube mesh is different than on extruded mesh

Tags: texturing, uv

I am creating some placeholder objects for size and scale and when I texture mapped a cube it seems different than a mesh created in a different manner. I must be missing something basic here but for the life of me can't see what's wrong.

Switching back and forth between the meshes they seem to have all the same properties. [Here is the link to the Blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/crv3h78r8qsackjro2i8v/Walls.blend?rlkey=vfilk238ahbuph8jqg6jy9p77&dl=0)

[image: Correct mapping]
[image: Incorrect mapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is not correctly unwrapped, look if I draw an horizontal line on the grid, it will appear vertical on your cube, you need to rotate your UV 90° then scale on X, or mark a seam on one of the vertical edges and unwrap again.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see. The UV coords are 0-1 range, but the anchors for the vertices aren't the same (e.g. rotated). Makes sense now. Thought I was going crazy. Thanks!